# How to receive incoming sms in twilio using c# webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio API to send and receive SMS in c#. I have implemented send SMS successfully. The problem is in receiving SMS. Twilio documentation only shows MVC code to receive SMS. Is it possible to receive SMS in asp.net web forms? 
Here is the documentation to receive SMS.
[Receive SMS in twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/09/an-easy-way-to-receive-an-sms-message-with-c-and-twilio.html)

My project is in asp.net web form. Do I need to switch to the MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

If you're using WebForms, I generally recommend receiving SMS messages using a Generic HTTP Handler.  Twilio passes parameters like the message body as form encoded params, so its easy to grab those from the request context.

```
public class Twiml : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";

        var Body = context.Request.Forms["Body"];

        var response = new Twilio.TwiML.MessageResponse();
        response.Message("You said: " + Body);

        context.Response.Write(response.ToString());
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes it works just a small change :  instead of 'response = new Twilio.TwiML.MessageResponse();' use 'response = new Twilio.TwiML.TwilioResponse();'

Comment: No, you would create a new HttpHandler class file and put this code in it.